# After upgrading to php 7 bin/magento CLI commands not working Magento 2.0.2 CE

Tags: cli, php-7, magento-2.0.2, bin-magento

I've upgraded the php version of the apache2.4 server from 5.6 to 7.0. 
OS version Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
After this update, despite the fact that I've installed php7.0-cli, when i try to run

```
php7.0 bin/magento list command
```

I get the fallowing output:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

bin/magento must be run as a CLI application
```

Output when I run sudo apt-get install php7.0-cli:

```
php7.0-cli is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

When I go to the bin directory and try to run the command :

```
magento list
```

I get the output:

```
magento: command not found
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what is the output of:

```
ls -l $(which php)
```

For me this is showing:

```
/usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php
```

Also check the output of this:

```
echo $PATH
```

And look for any path to the wrong php, maybe you only need to fix the $PATH.

If this is not working try this to reinstall the whole package, overwriting the original files:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php7.0-cli
```

Comment: Yeah... "sudo apt-get install --reinstall php7.0-cli" did the job. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

There is No need to reinstall PHP. You just do this command

```
php7.0-cli bin/magento
```

list command